# Why is there such a problem with the output of buttons?

Tags: reactjs

I am requesting to local server. And server returns me response:

```
{"total":7,
"perPage":3,
"page":1,
"lastPage":3,
 "data":[
     {"id":1,"title":"animals","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
     {"id":2,"title":"space","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
     {"id":3,"title":"sport","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."}
]}
```

- **data** - it list of category. And I display my list in the form of a table.
- **page** - it query param, the current page number
  If in field page would be number two, then it would be in data the another three objects. That is, there would be in data other categories, with another title and id.

I have task:
 - make pagination with three buttons.Because I have three page`"lastPage":3`.

And I did it(I comment where is the code that is responsible for the output of the buttons):

```
 const Home = () => {

     const [value, setValue] = useState({
         listCategory: [],
         currentPage: 1
     });

      useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData(currentPage) {
    try {
      const res = await apiCategory('api/categories', {
        method:'GET'
      }, currentPage);
      setValue({
        listCategory:res.data,
        currentPage:res.page
      });
    } catch(e) { 
      console.error(e);
    } 
  };
  fetchData(value.currentPage);
},[value.currentPage]);

   const changePage = (argPage) => {
   setValue((prev) => {
     return {
       ...prev,
       currentPage: argPage 
     }
   });
 }
      return (
        <div>
        <Table dataAttribute = {value.listCategory} />

       {value.listCategory.map((item, index) => (                 //output buttons
          <button key={'listCategory_'+index} 
                  onClick={() => changePage(index)}>{index}
          </button>
       ))}
        </div>
    )}
```

But then my button display **0 1 2** instead **1 2 3**:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/709f913a9db46b2b883aa0a6138a74fa/1587760982/23057/1372209/Screenshot_4.png

In addition, the 0 button does nothing.

Also I tried write like this:

```
 {value.listCategory.map((item, index) => (
      <button key={'listCategory_'+item.id} 
              onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}>{index + 1}
      </button>
      ))}
```

And then I have already **1 2 3** button, but when I click button **3** - buttons **2** and **3** disappear:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/99676a2369c659285d7178f5c8f81885/1587760999/13502/1372209/Screenshot_9.png

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page buttons need to map on how many pages you need. The reason the 2,3 disappeared on when you selected pages 3 is that the data array only had one value thus only one button.

Below is an updated version of your code. I added the `buttonsRequired` to your `value` be set by the max number of pages needed based on the `perPage` and `total` values.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 1,
    buttonsRequired: 0,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(currentPage) {
      try {
        const res = await apiCategory('api/categories', {
          method: 'GET',
        }, currentPage);
        setValue({
          listCategory: res.data,
          currentPage: res.page,
          buttonsRequired: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage),
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData(value.currentPage);
  }, [value.currentPage]);

  const changePage = (argPage) => {
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      currentPage: argPage,
    }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} />
      {
            [...Array(value.buttonsRequired)].map((_, index) => ( // output buttons
              <button
                key={`listCategory_${index}`}
                onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}
              >
                {index + 1}
              </button>
            ))
        }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: TypeError: value.buttonsRequired.map is not a function:
```45 |     <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} />
     | ^  46 |     {
  47 |           value.buttonsRequired.map((_, index) => ( // output buttons```

Comment: Screenshot error: http://i.piccy.info/i9/5a397263b5567cdcb3a8e22ac29d6084/1587765171/16868/1372209/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: I updated it to use an `Array` constructor to generate a blank array to map against

Comment: @ I see, thank you very much! Can you explain me in your answer, what do these lines,
in more detail:
this:```buttonsRequired: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage),``` and this:
```[...Array(value.buttonsRequired)].map((_, index) => ( // output buttons
              <button
                key={`listCategory_${index}`}```

Comment: From the data you returned it has both a `total` (i.e. the total items to be returned) and `perPage` (total items per page). `Math.ceil` rounds up the value. So all put together (7/3) 2.333 rounded up to 3.

`[...Array(value.buttonsRequired)]` creates an empty with length of `value.buttonsRequired`.

Comment: And what it is? ```(_,```  I see this for the first time

Comment: I used `(_,` since `item` was not used in the map. I just use it to easily see that only the `index` is used.

Comment: if you can, as you have time, describe these lines in more detail in your answer what's going on there. Because I need go to sleep...